# Networkx - ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)

Tags: python, networkx, osmnx

I encountered this error when setting the attribute values for the `networkx.MultiDiGraph` instance `G`. I am using the `set_edges_attributions` method. The code is as follows.

```py
# a lib I wrote myself
import dijkstra

for edge in G.edges():
    w = dijkstra.cost_cal(G, edge[0]) 
    print(w, edge)
    
    # G: networkx.MultiDiGraph
    # edge: a tuple with two node IDs
    # w: float
    nx.set_edge_attributes(G, {edge: {"cost": w}})
```

Out:

```py
0.05050505050505051 (1004215022, 1955253358)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [6], in <cell line: 6>()
      7 w = dijkstra.cost_cal(G, edge[0]) 
      8 print(w, edge)
----> 9 nx.set_edge_attributes(G, {edge: {"cost": w}})

File C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\PyGIS\lib\site-packages\networkx\classes\function.py:821, in set_edge_attributes(G, values, name)
    818 else:
    819     # `values` consists of doct-of-dict {edge: {attr: value}} shape
    820     if G.is_multigraph():
--> 821         for (u, v, key), d in values.items():
    822             try:
    823                 G[u][v][key].update(d)

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)
```

Comment: @Haoliang `set_edge_attributes` does take 2 parameters, the error is due to the incorrect dictionary format

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproducible example of the graph?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot it. The Graph: import osmnx as ox G = ox.graph_from_bbox(28.1992, 28.1950, 112.9643, 112.9686, network_type="all")

Comment: About the dict format, I referenced the doc of networkx [set_edge_attribute](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.classes.function.set_edge_attributes.html)

Comment: I provided an example graph and how to set the edge attributes

Comment: Can you try `for edge in G.edges:` (without parentheses)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not giving the correct edge format to [`set_edge_attributes`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.classes.function.set_edge_attributes.html). A [`MultiDiGraph`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/classes/multidigraph.html) edge is characterized by 3 values, the start node, end node, and key.

Example:

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.MultiDiGraph()
G.add_edges_from([('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('a', 'b')])

print(G.edges)
```

Output:

```
OutMultiEdgeView([('a', 'b', 0), ('a', 'b', 1), ('a', 'c', 0)])
```

You can see that we have two `a->b` edges, one with key 0, the second with key 1. All 3 parameters are required to uniquely identify an edge.

[image: MultiDiGraph]

So you need to use:

```
nx.set_edge_attributes(G, {('a', 'b', 0): {'cost': 42}})
```

But you likely only used:

```
nx.set_edge_attributes(G, {('a', 'b'): {'cost': 42}})
```

Note that, unlike `G.edges`, `G.edges()` doesn't output the key:

```
OutMultiEdgeDataView([('a', 'b'), ('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c')])
```

So use `G.edges` in your loop.